# Guardar etiquetas HTML en sql server y leerlas

Tags: html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Cuando guardo unas etiquetas de salto de linea en un texto en sql server, ese parametro lo leo atraves de un servicio y lo guardo en un ViewBag.

Al momento de mostrarlo en HTML el texto se muestra con las etiquetas.

Por ejemplo:

```
Hola esto es un texto <br /> de muestra.
```

¿Como hago para que HTML me pueda interpretar esas etiquetas?, no como texto sino como codigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes utilizar `Html.Raw`, el funciona para que el `Engine` de MVC no le aplique transformación al texto. En este [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) esta la información del método

Comment: Gracias amigo, era lo que buscaba.